# Do I need to clear timeouts if user leaves?

Tags: javascript, html

My website uses some timeouts and delays for animations. Do I need to clear these if the user leaves the page without these timers finishing? Is it unsafe at all to not do so?

i.e. (exaggerating a little) if I have setTimeout(func, 10000000) and the user leaves in a few seconds.

Comment: On the contrary. You cannot know when the user leaves your page, so you cannot have any code to execute in that case for certain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a JavaScript setTimeout function stop when page reloaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619864/does-a-javascript-settimeout-function-stop-when-page-reloaded)

Comment: @Bergi What about the `beforeunload` event?

Comment: @philraj Not "for certain". Sure, it often tells you when the page is going to unload, but a user can always choose to just shut down the tab/browser/PC without any of your code executing.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying, ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, as pointed on the responses, is `no`, you do not need to clear the timeouts before the user leaves.

**If you're working with a Single Page Application (SPA)**

If your app is a SPA, the browser doesn't actually reload, so the timers would still be called, even though the page has "changed". Thus, unless you want the timer to be shared across pages, you'd want clear them on page change.