# Will a function in html execute while it is not being navigated

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm running nodejs webserver and hosting multiple html files. I'm navigating through those html files with my  `main.html` using Iframe. One of those  sub html files execute a javascript function and will send a bit "1" in my server after a pre-setted time that will turn on an led. So my question is If I clicked a button that will execute the function in a html file and I navigated away from that html page, will the function still execute after some time while navigating a new html page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619864/does-a-javascript-settimeout-function-stop-when-page-reloaded

Comment: Not quite,  same page is being reloaded but  in my case loading an entirely different html file. But I guess it's not possible because onload functions are needed for calling stored data